# How do you parse a JSON file in Racket?

Tags: json, parsing, functional-programming, racket

I would like to parse a JSON file in Racket but I have no idea how to approach this and cannot find any similar examples. Can anyone give tips or examples of how this can be done?

Comment: Uh… that is not JSON. That is JavaScript. If it were just the object literal, it would be JSON, but the `var clubMember =` part is JavaScript code. If you actually want to parse JSON, though, use the [`json` module](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html).

Comment: The original question was unclear, as it stands its off-topic. Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To parse JSON in Racket, use [the built-in `json` module](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html). There are [a handful of functions for reading JSON](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html#%28part._.Parsing_.J.S.O.N_.Text_into_.J.S-.Expressions%29) depending on your particular use case, but the main ones to use are [`read-json`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._json%2Fmain..rkt%29._read-json%29%29) or [`string->jsexpr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/json/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._json%2Fmain..rkt%29._string-~3ejsexpr%29%29).

To read a file, use the `read-json` function with the [`call-with-input-file`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._call-with-input-file%29%29) function, which will handle opening and closing the file handle. For example, to read a file called `data.json`, you’d use this:

```
(call-with-input-file "data.json" read-json)
```

If you already have the JSON data stored in a string, use the `string->jsexpr` function, like this:

```
(string->jsexpr "{ \"foo\": 42 }")
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the invalid JSON example. I'm kind of new to programming and grabbed it from CodeAcademy's JSON introduction.

Comment: @j.doe No problem, everyone starts somewhere! For future reference, you can use the [search bar on the upper left hand corner of the Racket documentation to search the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org), and if you type in “json”, the `json` library comes right up.